# Finding $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_0$ such that $f(x_0)=\frac{f(x_1)+f(x_2)+f(x_3)}{3}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

> If $f$ is continuous in $[a,b]$ show that there exist $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_0$ in $[a,b]$ such that
> $$ f(x_0)=\frac{f(x_1)+f(x_2)+f(x_3)}{3}.$$

I tried to use the intermediate value theorem and the fact that $f$ attains a maximum and a minimum in the interval but I am stuck.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Can't you just take $x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3$ equal to each other?

Comment: May be you need a triplet of distinct points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will restrict to the non-trivial case in which $x_1\neq x_2\neq x_3$. Without loss, assume $x_1<x_2<x_3$. Since $f$ is continuous in the compact set $[x_1,x_3]$, we know, from the intermediate value theorem, that for any number $v$ such that:
$$
\min\{f(x_1),f(x_2),f(x_3)\}\leq v \leq \max\{f(x_1),f(x_2),f(x_3)\},
$$

there exists a value $x_0\in [x_1,x_3]$ such that:

$$
f(x_0)=v.
$$

Now, pick $3v=f(x_1)+f(x_2)+f(x_3)$.

Comment: but why its true that ((1)+(2)+(3))/3 is between max{(1),(2),(3)} andmin{(1),(2),(3)}?

Comment: The arithmetic mean between three points is between the min and max of those points. If it is not clear I can add a line, let me know.

Comment: no need, thanks a lot